# JSF Converter not converting between String and class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Changing the selectOneMenu to this. Solved the issue for me. Now my problem is that the page seems to be called several times ending up messing up the selection.

But switching the value to #{st} instead of serieType would solved the issue with failing to assign the string to the class. Now it's correctly handled as a class. This makes no sense whatsoever to me since I have another selectonemenu where I use the player which is another bean. and set the value to #{player} but anyway this works.

Now I just need to figure out why my selection is altered when calling the page again.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{st}" 
                    converter="serieTypeConverter" id="serieTypeList">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{serviceSerieType.serieTypes}"
                     var="st"
                     itemValue="#{st}"
                     itemLabel="#{st.serie_type}"
                     itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Additional information

Below suggested solution will not work. It actually end up trying to assign a SerieType class to the serieType.selectedValue eventhough it's prototype is this

```
private String selectedValue;

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{serieType.selectedValue}" 
                    converter="serieTypeConverter" id="serieTypeList">
                <f:selectItems value="#{serviceSerieType.serieTypes}"
                     var="st"
                     itemValue="#{st}"
                     itemLabel="#{st.serie_type}"
                     itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Somewhere in the form I get below error. I can figure out where it goes wrong. I can't see any apparent reason for it since I am using an identical converter for another class with just the class name changed. There is a service that return a SerieType class either by a long ID och string ID.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/BowlingFacelets] threw exception [Cannot convert Match of type class java.lang.String to class com.jk.hcp.SerieType] with root cause
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert Match of type class java.lang.String to class com.jk.hcp.SerieType
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:420)
```

These are the only two places in the xhtml it's used

```
<h:selectOneListbox size="1" value="#{serieType}" 
                    converter="serieTypeConverter" id="serieTypeList">
                <f:selectItems value="#{serviceSerieType.serieTypes}"
                     var="st"
                     itemValue="#{st}"
                     itemLabel="#{st.serie_type}"
                     itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
                </h:selectOneListbox>


<c:forEach var="list" items="#{serviceSeries.getClubAverages(club.name, serieType, calendarBean)}">
```

In the ServiceSerieType

```
public List<SerieType> getSerieTypes() {
public SerieType getSerieTypeByID(long id) {
public SerieType getSerieTypeByStringID(String id) {


@FacesConverter(value = "serieTypeConverter")
public class SerieTypeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        long idValue;
        try {
            idValue = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }


        ServiceSerieType serviceSerieType = 
                context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{serviceSerieType}", ServiceSerieType.class);

        SerieType serieType = serviceSerieType.getSerieTypeByID(idValue);

        return serieType;

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, 
                                  UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(((SerieType)value).getStringID()); 
        }
    }

}

@ManagedBean
public class SerieType implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String serie_type;
    private String serie_type_info;


    public String getSerie_type_info() {
        return serie_type_info;
    }

    public void setSerie_type_info(String serie_type_info) {
        this.serie_type_info = serie_type_info;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SerieType() {
        super();
    }   

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
    public String getSerie_type() {
        return this.serie_type;
    }

    public void setSerie_type(String serie_type) {
        this.serie_type = serie_type;
    }

    public String getStringID() {
        if (id == null)
            return "0";
        return id.toString();
    }

    public void setStringID(String value) {
        if (value == null)
            return;

        try {
            this.id = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (id != null && other != null && getClass() == other.getClass())
             ? id.equals(((SerieType) other).getId())
             : (other == this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id != null) 
             ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode()) 
             : super.hashCode();
    }
    /*
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.serie_type + " " + this.serie_type_info;
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why your ManagedBean has a persistence @GeneratedValue annotation on a member field ?!
you are mixing between entity and managed bean !

Comment: Are there any 'caused by' exceptions?

Comment: There are no caused by. Yes it's also used for JPA. I can't see any reason to have one bean and one JPA class for the same thing. But maybe you can enlighten me?